# How to fix "amp-autocomplete data property 'value' must map to string type.' error in amp-autocomplete

Tags: amp-html

I want to set up a feature that allows my users to search for products on a Woocommerce site.
I use for this, the amp-autocomplete component.
When searching, the following error appears: amp-autocomplete data property "value" must map to string type.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

make sure the filter-value property is set in the amp-autocomplete tag

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data is either invalid or missing. [Validate your JSON.](https://jsonlint.com/)